# AttributeError when modifying vector layer symbology with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, vector-layer, attributeerror

In QGIS 3.22 I'm facing a problem with `QgsMapLayer`. I want to use it on QGIS in order to modify the symbology of line, point & polygon in each layer but every time it gives me an error on using the library of PyQGIS.

This is the script I'm using:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import * 

lyr = QgsVectorLayer("PATH", 'ligne', 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
sym = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({'Line_style': 'dash', 'Color': 'red'})
symbol = lyr.QgsMapLayer.createMapRenderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())
sym = symbols[0]
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

And here is the error message:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'QgsMapLayer'
> ```

Is there is any solution for that?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do but try this:

```py
lyr = QgsVectorLayer("PATH", 'ligne', 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)

sym = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({'line_style':'dash', 'color':'red'})
lyr.renderer().setSymbol(sym)
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

`line_style` and `color` are case-sensitive. Don't use `Line_style` and `Color`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for tour answer, but when i run tour code it gives me this errer: 

AttributeError: 'QgsRuleBasedRenderer' object has no attribute 'setSymbol'

And every time i try to change it ,like  instead of setsymbol i write only  symbol .

Sometimes this error ut shows up with renderer.

Comment: You didn't mention the layer had Rule-based symbology. The answer is about "Single Symbol"

Comment: Thank you @Kadir for tour help , it's guide me getter to identify the problem with my code .
I still have one question : How to change renderer type from Rule-based to single symbol? Or how to directly change the symbology of a Rule-bases